# How to find match in list inside element in python

Tags: python

I have below list :

```
print(set(list(filter(regex.search, mylist))

{'/var/data/java1.2/jre/bin/java\tAD1.8_138-x11#', 
'/var/data/java1.2/bin/java (date=02/02/1600)',
'/var/data/java1.2/jre/bin/java ([date=02/02/1600)\t',
'/var/data/java1.2/bin/java\tADn1.5_564'
}
```

After apply `set`, I getting above data where still seems same data. which I wish to get unique like :

Desire output:

```
/var/data/java1.8/bin/java
/var/data/java1.8/jre/bin/java
```

Can you please share your thoughts with in-build lib.

Comment: how's `mylist` looking ?

Comment: @dejdej `mylist` contain many duplicate value which same as mentioned 4 line in question.

Comment: It depends how you define uniqueness. Does it have an special pattern ? for example only  check 5 subdirectory.

Comment: No special pattern, that's why I want to find unique element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not the best approach, but seems to do the trick:

```py
s={'/var/data/java1.2/bin/java\tADn1.5_564', 
'/var/data/java1.2/jre/bin/java ([date=02/02/1600)\t',
'/var/data/java1.2/jre/bin/java\tAD1.8_138-x11#', 
'/var/data/java1.2/bin/java (date=02/02/1600)'}

l=[]

for i in s:
    l.append(i.split()[0])

ll=set(l)

print(ll)
#{'/var/data/java1.2/bin/java', '/var/data/java1.2/jre/bin/java'}
```